# MS Excel populate columns based on other column

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets

### Sheet1:

```
CLASS_CD                CLASS_NME
--------                ---------
000                     Jan
001                     Feb
002                     Mar
003                     Apr
004                     May
005                     June
006                     July
007                     Aug           
008                     Sep
```

### Sheet2:

```
SUB_CD      CLASS_CD    CLASS_NME
------      --------    ---------
1003        000                     
1004        001                     
1005        001 
1006        001 
1008        002 
1010        002 
1014        003 
1015        003 
1017        004 
1019        005 
1021        005 
1022        006 
1026        007 
1028        007 
1029        008
```

the first sheet have unique CLASS_CD and based on the CLASS_CD I want to populate the second sheet CLASS_NME, is there any formula to do this? 
help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

[image]